# Woocommerce sorting and ajax add to cart

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Im using woocommerce on my WP site and i have two problems. I tried really googeling about it and i couldnt find answer. 
First is: In settings there is button "enable ajax for add to cart on archive page" and that is ticked but it doesnt work :S  No matter what i do it always refreshes web page and puts in query string to add to cart. This works only on "tab" with suggested or simmilar products, then when i click on add to cart in listed simmilar products it adds to cart over ajax. I noticed class changes so i made loading bar and stuff according to them. But it just wont work on archive page :S  Any ideas?

Second problem is, i have

```
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
```

in archive-product.php and that i assume calls catalog ordering. And catalog ordering appears on page but nothing works when selecting options. Its just like inactive select box and thats it. This is my second issue. Im trying to solve this for two days without luck. Any help appriciated. Thanks

Comment: You should separate these into their own separate questions.

Comment: Both the issues look related to some JS errors on your site, have you checked the console for JS errors?

Comment: Im sorry for making two questions here :S Didnt want to spam with posts.  @Anand there is no error in console, but further more for sorting, there is no POST beeing made in console whatsoever when changing sorting options like it should do it when ajax is used. :S Im so confused over this...

Comment: Do you have a test URL where this can be checked?

Comment: i am sorry for late reply, i was trying to fix that and i putted it on live server under maintenance mode and opened guest account just so you can see if you have interest maybe. is it possible to get your skype id just to send you link and accont maybe? then i will rate your answer here? :S thanks alot.
P.s. noticed that ajax or widgets dont work when woocommmerce.php calls for "( 'archive-product.php' );"   i tryed replacing file with original and still the same. when woocommerce.php redirects to  <?php if ( is_singular( 'product' ) ) {
     woocommerce_content();  ..then is ok

Comment: close the toppic.... its solved..im idiot... my footer wasnt loading corectly because of some script, but wasnt giving errors..